# About a $4$ dimensional representation of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters, permutation-cycles

In the book **Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicist** of A.Zee, the reader has been asked to compute the characters of a given $4$ dimensional representation of $S_4$.
Taking the 4 elements to permute in a column, we can use this $4$dim representation like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}c \\ a \\ b \\ d\end{bmatrix}$$

Where the 4x4 Matrix corresponds to the cycle $(1 2 3)$.

Let's call the representation $D(g)$, where $g\in S_4$ and its character as $C$.

So, taking one representative for each $S_4$ conjugacy class, we can have:

- $C(D((e))) = 4$
- $C(D((1 2 3))) = 1$
- $C(D((1 2))) = 2$
- $C(D((1 2)(3 4))) = 0$
- $C(D((1 2 3 4))) = 0$

I've checked them carefully and they seem to me correct.

Now, as usual, I start wondering if this representation is reducible. Currently we know from the $S_4$ character table we have 5 irreps with dimension $1, 1, 2, 3, 3$.

So this representation is not reducible but could be gotten from the above ones.

I was wondering if it could be gotten as a direct product of the matrices of the $2$dim representation.

May be you give me some hints if this could be right or eventually point me to the right solution, please?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've tried to build the **Canonical Jordan Form** of the given 4x4 matrix, getting:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}(1 + i\sqrt 3) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}(1 - i\sqrt 3)\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I should be able to recognize some blocks of dimension 1 and 3 in there, related to the 2 irreps. My bet is the first block is the top left most 1, i.e. the $S_4$ trivial representation, and the other 3 entries are forming the other 3dim irrep. Inspecting the character of this latter for the group element $(1 2 3)$ gives $0$, which is **exactly** the character of the **3dim standard representation**.
Of course I should check the other $S_4$ class characters to have a complete match, but my bet is my representation is the **direct sum of the $S_4$ trivial representation and the standard one**.
Is there a precise way to check claim this without checking all characters and match the character table for the standard representation?

Tx

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you ask about the decomposition of this representation? If so, it has a $1$-dimensional invariant subspace of vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ a \\ a \\ a\end{bmatrix}$, and also a $3$-dimensional invariant subspace of vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix}$ where $a+b+c+d=0$. It can be checked that these two representations are irreducible, and so they give the (unique) decomposition of your representation.

Comment: Yes I meant decomposition in terms of known irreps of $S_4$. Still not clear how these 2 irreps can compose to generate mine and, if these 2 can be listed in the $S_4$ character table.

Comment: Just to clarify Better the representation  Is the 4x4 Matrix, not the column vector

Comment: It sounds like you want to conjugate the $4\times4$-matrices you have in such a way that they have the diagonal block structure $1\times1$ + $3\times3$. To do that observe that the vector $v=\frac12(1,1,1,1)^T$ from Mark's comment is a common eigenvector (belonging to $\lambda=1$) of all the $24$ matrices. The matrices you have are  all orthogonal and preserve the usual inner product. So all you need to do is to extend $v$ to an orthonormal basis, and then do the resulting similarity transformation to all the matrices.

Comment: (cont'd) But it will help your studies immensely to familiarize with the concept of a representation as a module. When a module is a direct sum of two submodules (as Mark described), the matrix rep immediately gets the block structure.

Comment: OK I partially got It. So basically my representation Is a direct sum of a 1d One and 3d One, turning the Matrix in blocks. Without example Is not Easy but I will try. Originally I was puzzled if It could be gotten as a direct product of two 2d irreps

Comment: So if I can find a similarity transformation Matrix Is tantamount to claim the representation Is reducible, right?

Comment: I was able to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors and I understood finally the comments above. My current trial Is focused in finding the Jordan Canonical Form of the Matrix,  which Is block diagonal. I'm puzzled since, due to $\lambda=1$ which Is doubled I would get too many blocks.